# Explain why the equation $x^3 - 15x +1 = 0$ has at least three solutions in the interval [-4,4].

Tags: limits, continuity

Explain why the equation

$$x^3 - 15x +1 = 0$$

has at least three solutions in the interval [-4,4].

My thoughts:

$$f(x) = x^3 - 15x + 1$$
$$f(-4) = -3 $$
$$f(4) = 5 $$
$$f(-4) < 0 < f(4)$$
Therefore, by IVT, there exist some $c \in [-4,4]$ such that $f(c)=0$ exist.

However, I am unable how to prove there are at least three solutions...

Comment: Look at a few more values, for example $\,f(\pm 1)\,$.

Comment: If you are using the intermediate value theorem you need to isolate three different intervals in which the sign changes, so you need more data points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to identify the turning points of $f(x)$ by setting $f'(x)=3x^2-15=0$ so that $x=\pm \sqrt 5$ these lie between $x=\pm 4$ and the general shape of the curve gives a local maximum at $x=-\sqrt 5$. Since $f(0)=1$ it is easy to see that the value at the maximum is positive. Continue analysis to identify what you need.

Answer (score 1):

This proves it has at least one solution.

**Hint**:

Show $f(x)$ has a local maximum and a local minimum on $[-4,4]$,  and that the maximum is positive and the minimum is negative.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(-4)=-3$$
$$f(0)=1$$
$$f(1)=-13$$
$$f(4)=5$$

By IVT, there are at least three roots

one in $(-4,0)$ ,

one in $(0,1)$,

and one in $(1,4)$.

A polynom with degee $3$ cannot have more than three roots.

If it had four roots, the derivative will have three roots (By Rolle).

but $$f'(x)=3x^2-15$$

which have only two roots.
So, $$x^3-15x+1=0$$ has exactly three real solutions.